# Proper way to load local stored images from folder in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling the OpenWeatherMap API and getting in the response the `iconID` like `01d` or `04n`. I've set up all the images under a local directory in `/src` and named them `01d.png`, `04n.png` etc.

I've passed this `iconID` via `props` to my `Current.js` component and I don't know how can I display the image with the specific id name.

**E.G:**

I would like to display image `01d.png` if the response from the server is equal to  `01d`

**P.S:**

`props.icon` stores the data from the server and it is indeed good data.

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Current.module.css';

const current = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Current}>
            <p>Temperature: {props.temperature}</p>
            <p>Minimum Temperature: {props.minimumTemperature}</p>
            <p>Maximum Temperature: {props.maximumTemperature}</p>
            <p>Humidity: {props.humidity}</p>
            <img src={'../../icons/' + props.icon + '.png'}[enter image description here][1] alt={props.icon}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default current;
```

Here is a screenshot of my folder structure

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that the images folder is not out of `src`, then load image like

```
<img src={require(`../../icons/${props.icon}.png`)} />
```

Or if it is only one image id passed to component and no need for maping you can lazy load it when component renders.

```
const current = (props) => {
   const pic = React.lazy(()=>import(`../../icons/${props.icon}.png`))
   ......
```

Then wrap the `img` tag with `Suspense` and  `<img src={pic} />`